# Update Photo on iOS

Tags: ios, photos, image-editing

I would like to update a photo (Photo A) with another (Photo B).

The result should be that Photo A looks like Photo B, but can be reverted back to Photo A. Is there an extension that will let me do this on iOS? I am using the External Editors extension to achieve this on the Mac.

For example, on a Mac I can choose to edit a RAW image from the Photos app with Lightroom and I then end up with two identical images.

I would like to be able to do the same sort of thing in iOS so that I can edit a RAW file and then revert back to it later, but without having to see it in the library.

Comment: Can you please clarify?

Comment: I think my steps are fairly clear, but I can give some background. If I shoot a RAW image and edit it with Lightroom, I end up with two identical images. I would like to update the RAW file with edits, so I can revert to it later, but without having to see it in the library.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're referring to the `Photos.app` library and application in terms of wanting it not to be visible in the library: You can hide the old RAWs so they don't show up in the main views of the library, though they'll still be there (which is good in the case you want to revert to them) - you can set the old RAW as Hidden on iOS by selecting it in the library and pressing the action button (the blue square and up arrow) and then selecting Hide Photo. They won't appear in your main library then, but rather only in a Hidden album.

To get them back in the main library, first go to the Hidden album and select the RAWs you want back. Then you can use the action button and select Unhide to have them reappear in the main library.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you're not aware, iOS does support photo extensions that allow users to do more advanced editing of their images.

You can use photo extensions as follows:

1. Launch the Photos app
2. Select a photo you'd like to edit
3. Tap the *Edit* option at top right
4. Tap on the *More* icon in the menubar at bottom of the screen (i.e. the circle icon with the three dots in it)
5. Now you'll see a list of apps that support photo extensions<sup>1</sup>
6. Tap on the one(s) you want to access for editing your photo with

<sup>1. Many photo imaging apps support photo extensions. Those that do will appear here. You can also reorder these apps by holding their icon down and moving them around.</sup>